# Ошибки сборки и запуска проекта в Visual Studio

Tags: winapi, c, visual-studio-2010

Я учусь писать приложения в Visal Studio 2010 и сразу же столкнулся с проблемой: не работает простенькая программа, которая просто создает окно. Возникли две ошибки: 1) синтаксическая ')'; 2) не может найти одноименный .exe файл, наверное, потому что я его не создавал (но по книги и не требовалось).

У кого есть опыт работы в Visual Studio 2010, подскажите, что не так? Так как код стандартный и у вас не должен вызвать вопросов, поэтому бросаю его весь, посмотрите, пожалуйста, у себя, почему появляются эти ошибки?

У кого есть опыт работы в Visual Studio 2010, подскажите что не так?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
TCHAR WinName[] = _T("MainFrame");

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE This, HINSTANCE Prev, LPTSTR cmd, int mode)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.hInstance = This;
    wc.lpszClassName = WinName;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WIN DOW + 1);
    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        return 0;

    hWnd = CreateWindow(WinName, _T("Каркас Window-приложения"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, HWND_DESKTOP, NULL, This, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, mode);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, l Param);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `COLOR_WIN DOW -> COLOR_WINDOW, l Param -> lParam`. Больше пока не вижу, может невнимательно смотрю.

Comment: Вторая ошибка из-за того что не был собран проект из-за первой ошибки